# Where can I find information on the licence(s) that govern use of the fonts that come preinstalled on Mac OS X?

Tags: font, license

I've just read the licence for the Hoefler font (see [their EULA](http://www.typography.com/home/eula.php)).  It says explicitly:

> You may not create Embedded Documents, except as expressly provided in paragraphs 3.2 and 3.3:

and "Embedded Documents" includes "ordinary" PDFs.

Now it may be that Apple has a different licence that is in force when I "bought" this font through Mac OS X.  If so, where do I find it?  (More generally, for any font distributed with Mac OS X.)  I'd quite like to know that if I create a PDF with one of these fonts then I'm not breaking the law.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the os license:

E. Fonts. Subject to the terms and conditions of this License, you may use the fonts included with the Apple Software to display and print content while running the Apple Software; however, you may only embed fonts in content if that is permitted by the embedding restrictions accompanying the font in question. These embedding restrictions can be found in the Font Book/Preview/Show Font Info panel.

In FontBook Show Info for Hoefler Text it says "Embeddable: Yes".

Comment: I did not find "Embeddable" information in FontBook in macOS 10.12